# How to set a string from a previously defined string in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have the following code:

```
public void onClickV(View view){
 String title = "Go To...";
}

public void showDialog (View arg0) {
dialog.setTitle(this.String.title);
}
```

But the "this.String.title" isn't working at all. How could I set the title of the dialog depending on what the string is set to by an onClick method?

Thanks

EDIT: How would I do something similar for images?

Comment: You may want to place such strings in `strings.xml` and use `getString()` to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use harcoded String. Use a string ressource.

In strings.xml

```
<string name="title">Go to...</string>
```

In Activity.java

```
public void showDialog(View arg0) {
    dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.title));
}
```

Comment: I will definitely be using this in the future for making apps for multiple languages, Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Declare a variable outside the function.

```
String title;

public void onClickV(View view){
  title = "Go To...";
}

public void showDialog (View arg0) {
dialog.setTitle(title);
}
```

Comment: baptisterobert provided also a good alternative (mostly if you want to support multi-languages)